# INSERT statement will not let me use IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I have an insert statement that I can't get to work the way I want it to. It's on a vb.net page. This is on a VB.net page and I'm using SQL Server 2005 for my database.

```
Dim strSQL As String = "IF NOT EXISTS
(SELECT Title From Picklist) 
BEGIN INSERT INTO Picklist (Title, Data) 
VALUES (@Title, @Data);

INSERT INTO Marketing 
(ProductID, MarketingTypeID, MarketingTitle, MarketingData) 
VALUES (@ProductID, 9, 'Video', scope_identity()) END"
```

I don't get an error and nothing gets inserted into the database. If I try putting the END at the end of the first INSERT statement then I get an error saying that MarketingData is NULL and cannot be inserted.

But if I take out the IF NOT EXISTS from the statement, everything gets inserted perfectly. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:** Is it correct to write the statement like this?

```
INSERT INTO Marketing
SELECT (@ProductID, @MarketingTypeID, @MarketingTitle, @MarketingData)
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM Marketing)
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: Is the Picklist table empty? If not, your IF NOT EXISTS condition will be false.

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm using SQLServer 2008 and VB.net 4.0

Comment: @jlg - And what are the desired semantics? You are trying to insert a row into `Picklist` only if it doesn't already exist? And if so what constitutes it already existing? The `Title` already exists? Or the `Title, Data` combination already exists?

Comment: @IanNelson the Picklist table has a lot of data in it, this query actually works on other MarketingTitles (Video is just one of the types of Titles in the database - there is also Documents, Images, blah blah blah) The IF NOT EXISTS query works when I try to insert an image into the database.

Comment: @MartinSmith I was going for only if the Title already exists, I had the statement as `IF NOT EXISTS SELECT Title from Picklist` but somewhere along the way I must've changed it, dumb error. I will change that back though, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Did you add a BEGIN with your END? (In addition to the issues already mentioned with the IF EXISTS query.)

Comment: Yep, I have the BEGIN right before the INSERT INTO

Comment: It's definitely the IF NOT EXISTS, I must be writing it wrong or something. I have tried using it on other pages in this site but it won't insert anything. `IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT column FROM table) BEGIN INSERT INTO table columns END` Is there a reason that this would NOT work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Picklist)` will skip the insert if any rows at all exist in `Picklist`.

From your description of what happens when you change the position of the `END` it seems there are rows in the table.

I assume in fact you are trying to do an `UPSERT`. What version of SQL Server are you on? If 2008 look into `MERGE`

```
;WITH Source(Title, Data) AS
(
SELECT @Title, @Data
)
MERGE Picklist AS T
USING Source S
ON (T.Title = S.Title)


WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (Title, Data)
    VALUES (@Title, @Data)
    ;

IF (@@ROWCOUNT <> 0)
INSERT INTO Marketing 
            (ProductID, MarketingTypeID, MarketingTitle, MarketingData) 
     VALUES (@ProductID, 9, 'Video', scope_identity())
```

Comment: @jlg - I've added a `MERGE` version that gives the semantics you state in the comments.

Comment: Dangit, someone edited my tags! This is on a vb.net page by the way. Does that matter? I wouldn't think it would because it's still an sql statement

Comment: @jlg - No. Shouldn't do. I made some fixes to it from the original post so make sure you use the current version not any previous one.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying `Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE'.
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.`

Comment: That doesn't sound like you are on 2008 then

Comment: What is the result of `select @@version, compatibility_level from sys.databases where database_id=DB_ID()`

Comment: Oh, my boss told me wrong then. It says SQL server 2005 compatibility level 90. Sorry about that, I wasn't aware that I had misleading information.